# Can I generate multisig addresses directly in the coldcard?

Tags: wallet, coldcard

According to coldcard's multisig video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OMpZ5heLsRg I need to export the 3 xpubs and then create a multisig wallet in each coldcard using these 3 xpubs. Then it exports a list of addresses that can be plugged into Electrum.

However, I don't wanna trust seeing this list on the computer. Can I see these addresses on the coldcard itself?

Like, generate/visualize one address at the coldcard and then compare it with the electrum one just to be sure I'm sending to my wallet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging the source code for 2 days I found it. YES, it's possible.

When you power your coldcard, select Address Explorer, then CC 2-of-2 (in my case) and then you'll be able to see your addresses. However I think you cannot see them entirely, just the beggining and end.

PS: these are testnet addresses for a disposable wallet for my tests

[image]

[image]

[image]